# Grouping and Ordering through multiple associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Models:

```
class BacklinkReport
  has_many :backlinks, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :domains, through: :backlinks
  has_many :pages, through: :backlinks
  has_many :domain_scores, through: :domains
  has_many :page_scores, through: :pages
end

class Backlink
  belongs_to :domain
  has_many :domain_scores, through: :domains
end

class Domain 
  has_many :pages
  has_many :domain_scores
end

class DomainScores
  belongs_to :domain
end
```

Through ActiveRecord, I need a list of the unique domains for a given backlink_report, sorted by their MAX(domain_score.date) and ultimately ordered by their domain_score.pa score.

**EDIT:**

I'm currently breaking the query up into two parts. The first joins the backlinks from a particular report on all Domains and groups by ID to receive a list of unique domains for this particular report. Then I map the list by most recent DomainScore for each domain and sort by domain_score.da. This second query takes quite some time as it runs a DomainScore lookup on each of the 15k or so domains associated with the report. With the associations above, is there a more efficient way to achieve my outcome? I'd also like to be able to limit the number of highest ranking domains I'm requesting vs. fetching the entire site.

```
domains = Domain.joins(:backlinks).where(:backlinks => {:backlink_report_id => report_id}).group('domains.id')
domains = domains.map{|d| d.domain_scores.sort_by{|x| x['date']}.last}.compact.sort_by(&:da).reverse!
```

Comment: Please share what you’ve tried so far, and how what you’ve tried isn’t aligning with what you would like to achieve. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you. I've added my current attempt to the original post.